# Cargo activates features by itself

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a binary that depends on a library. In the library I specified these features:

```
[features]
default = []
fet = []
```

I would expect feature `fet` would ONLY be activated when it is compiled with the feature flag. In my binary the `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[dependencies]
a = { path = "./a" }

[features]
default = []
```

I haven't specified the `fet` feature in the `Cargo.toml`, however this gives me a compilation error in my binary:

```
fn main() {
    if cfg!(feature = "fet") {
        compile_error!("not expected");
    }
}
```

Why is feature `fet` still activated in my binary? I executed these commands and get the same error:

```
cargo run
cargo run --features=default
```

Ideally, I want my binary to activate certain features from dependencies if they are explicitly mentioned in the `cargo run` command (in the `--features` flag). Is this possible? I was hoping this would work in my binary `Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
default = []
fet = ["a/fet"]
```

and feature `fet` would be activated if I ran this command:

```
cargo run --features=fet
```

Comment: are you sure you understand https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html  ? What you do here is a runtime check but compile error is a ... compiler time error

Comment: more about feature https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`cfg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.cfg.html) macro will be expanded to `true` or `false` depending on if the condition is true or false, so if the feature flag is not set, it will still expand to this:

```rust
fn main() {
    if false {
        compile_error!("not expected");
    }
}
```

The `compile_error!` macro will still be invoked, so you'll get the compiler error either way.

The `cfg!` macro is mostly useful when you can rely on the compiler optimizing away branches that will never be taken, such as an `if false` branch. The code still needs to compile before optimization, though, so it's less useful when the code will only compile if the condition is true or false.

What you'd want to use instead is either a [`#[cfg]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) attribute or the [`cfg_if::cfg_if!`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/1.0.0/cfg_if/index.html) macro:

```rust
// with #[cfg] attribute

fn main() {
    #[cfg(feature = "fet")]
    compile_error!("not expected");
}

// with cfg_if!
use cfg_if::cfg_if;

fn main() {
    cfg_if!{
        if #[cfg(feature = "fet")] {
            compile_error!("not expected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks! The actual problem was pretty odd. I had another dependency on "a" in my dev-dependencies with the features flag inlined (a = { path = "./a", features=["fet"] }). This caused the feature to be turned on automatically when just running cargo run. Not sure if this is intended from cargo

Comment: @NoKey If you want dev-dependencies' features to not affect regular dependencies (at the cost of additional builds), use `resolver = "2"`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-resolver-version-2